# Optimize writing ods files with simple-odf

Tags: java, odftoolkit

This is my code to write my file:

```
    SpreadsheetDocument ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument();
    Table table = Table.newTable(ods, 4000, 20, 0, 0);
    table.setTableName("foo");
    Border border = new Border(Color.BLACK, 1, StyleTypeDefinitions.SupportedLinearMeasure.PT);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.BOLD, 7, Color.BLACK);
    List<Row> rows = table.getRowList();

    for (Row r : rows) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
            Cell cell = r.getCellByIndex(a);
            cell.setStringValue("Foo " + a);
            cell.setBorders(CellBordersType.ALL_FOUR, border);
            cell.setCellBackgroundColor(Color.valueOf("#A5A5A5"));
            cell.setFont(font);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignmentType.CENTER);
        }
    }

    ods.save("K://foo.ods");
```

In this code I set the style at the cell level. To optimize the writing I want to know if there is any way to do for row or table level. Or create a style for border, font, size, etc ... in the document and set style with function setCellStyleName. I can do something like this?

The reason is because I get this error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:814)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.updateSelectedKeys(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:496)
>     at
>   sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:172)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:1050)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If I delete the format (border, font ...), I can write more rows.
If I open the content.xml, I can see that I have many defined styles that are equal.
I'm using this version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.odftoolkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-odf</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Not experienced with simple odf, but Document,getOrCreateDocumentStyle. Also repeatedly creating new instances, like Color.valueOf have an impact on memory.

Comment: Did you try to give the program a little bit more memory?

Comment: @Joop Eggen Thanks for your info. I define a color once outside loop, this way Color color = Color.valueOf("#A5A5A5"); but i get the same error.

Comment: I change the values in my STS.ini (I use Spring tool suite) but nothing changes. My values: -vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1024m
@RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code of apply ODF style to cell. I cannot find a easy solution to create style. What I do is createing a ods file, check the child element of `office:automatic-styles` in `content.xml` then convert it to java code.

```
    SpreadsheetDocument ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument();
    Table table = Table.newTable(ods, 4000, 20, 0, 0);
    table.setTableName("foo");
    //create style
    OdfOfficeAutomaticStyles astyles = ods.getContentDom().getOrCreateAutomaticStyles();
    StyleStyleElement ele = astyles.newStyleStyleElement(OdfStyleFamily.TableCell.getName(), "myss");
    StyleTableCellPropertiesElement styleTableCellPropertiesElement = ele.newStyleTableCellPropertiesElement();
    styleTableCellPropertiesElement.setFoBackgroundColorAttribute("#A5A5A5");
    styleTableCellPropertiesElement.setFoBorderAttribute("1.0pt solid #000000");
    ele.newStyleParagraphPropertiesElement().setFoTextAlignAttribute(HorizontalAlignmentType.CENTER.toString());
    StyleTextPropertiesElement styleTextPropertiesElement = ele.newStyleTextPropertiesElement(null);
    styleTextPropertiesElement.setStyleFontNameAttribute("Arial");
    styleTextPropertiesElement.setFoFontSizeAttribute("7.0pt");
    styleTextPropertiesElement.setFoColorAttribute(Color.BLACK.toString());
    styleTextPropertiesElement.setFoFontWeightAttribute("bold");

    List<Row> rows = table.getRowList();
    for (Row r : rows) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            Cell cell = r.getCellByIndex(a);
            cell.setStringValue("Foo " + a);
            cell.setCellStyleName("myss");
        }
    }
```